# Flutter Row widget with two two text widget is not following one another

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-test, flutter-text, flutter-row

I am trying to wrap text (multi line) followed by "Read More" in a Row widget.

Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. **Read More...**

I tried using row widget **(Read More)** it's overflowing to next line.

Just want to show the readmore text followed by the content without overflowing to next line. on clicking read more i am showing bottommodelsheet.

Please help..

Comment: could you please include your as well?

Comment: Please provide some code so that others can better understand or reproduce the problem. Read more on [Ask]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `RichText` instead of `Row`:

```
RichText(
                text: TextSpan(
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                  children: <TextSpan>[
                    TextSpan(
                      text:
                          "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.",
                    ),
                    TextSpan(
                      text: 'Read more!',
                      style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                      recognizer: TapGestureRecognizer()
                        ..onTap = () {
                          print('Read more click');
                          // what you wnat when click more
                        },
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks for the response.. It worked. Actually earlier I tried with Richtext.. but unfortunately I am unaware of TapGestureRecognizer. Thanks it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [readmore](https://pub.dev/packages/readmore) package for this.

```dart
ReadMoreText(
  "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.",
  trimLines: 2,
  colorClickableText: Colors.pink,
  trimMode: TrimMode.Line,
  trimCollapsedText: 'Show more',
  trimExpandedText: 'Show less',
  moreStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 14, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
);
```

Comment: Many thanks for the response. the package doesn't solve the purpose. when user click on the read more.. i am showing a bottom model sheet on tap of readmore.. I just want to show the readmore text followed by multi line text.

Comment: Can you include [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

To do this simply add a package `readmore: ^2.1.0`.

In your .dart file import `import 'package:readmore/readmore.dart';`

Use this code to adjust automatically height of container

```
Container(
                        margin: const EdgeInsets.only(
                          top: 30,
                          left: 10,
                          right: 10,
                          bottom: 40.0,
                        ),
                        color: Colors.transparent,
                        child: ReadMoreText(
                          'your_text',
                          trimLines: 4,
                          colorClickableText: Colors.pink,
                          trimMode: TrimMode.Line,
                          trimCollapsedText: 'Show more',
                          postDataTextStyle: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.blue,
                          ),
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontFamily: 'Avenir',
                            color: Colors.black,
                          ),
                          trimExpandedText: 'Show less',
                          lessStyle: TextStyle(
                            fontFamily: 'Avenir',
                            fontSize: 16.0,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            color: Colors.blue,
                          ),
                          moreStyle: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 16,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          ),
                        ),
                        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                      ),
```

Comment: Many thanks for the response. the package doesn't solve the purpose. when user click on the read more.. i am showing a bottom model sheet on tap of readmore.. I just want to show the readmore text followed by multi line text.